# Cisco IOS programming, automation, and information

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios

I'm confused about Cisco IOS, and I have some question about that.

Cisco IOS is used in routers and other devices.

Is it possible to write code (like PHP) for that?

If it's possible, what language can I use?

The thing that confuses me is not how to work with Cisco IOS; it's about whether I can develop and change my router or other devices according to what I need for the network or not?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. Almost every<sup>Note 1</sup> Cisco IOS system running at least IOS 12.2 has [built-in tcl shell programmability](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/ios_tcl/configuration/12-4t/ios-tcl-12-4t-book/nm-script-tcl.html).  You can store tcl scripts in flash and run them.
2. Cisco IOS also has a light native programming environment called EEM (Embedded Event Manager).  EEM events can be triggered by a wide variety of inputs, such as packets on a certain port (via Netflow), log messages, or interface up/down.  Think of EEM as a subset of tclsh capabilities in IOS; EEM sucks less than programming in TCL, but you also get spotty feature support depending on the IOS mix you are dealing with.  EEM can be run on a cron schedule if that suits your needs.  At the bottom of [this answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12878/cisco-ios-cli-prompts-any-way-to-know-which-interface-you-are-configuring/12896#12896), I included an example EEM script; keep in mind that EEM is best for small-ish numbers of "if-this, do-that" statements... when you want to start defining functions and such, just bite the bullet and use `tclsh`.
3. New Cisco products support a special set of canned SDN APIs which are broader than I can explain while typing on my mobile phone; one example from this family includes [Cisco APIC](https://www.sdxcentral.com/resources/cisco/what-is-cisco-apic/), but that's just scratching the surface of what they have available.
4. I would be remiss if I didn't point out that most of the Cisco scripting done in the last 20 years has been via [screen-scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27896298/expect-script-for-cisco-juniper-config-backup), snmp, and (these-days) NETCONF.  Anything you can do from the CLI, can be automated via screen-scraping; I have spent a large portion of my career doing just this. Screen-scrapers usually host their scripts on an external linux system and connect to a router with the weapon of their own choice... usually that's one of these languages:

   - TCL / Expect
   - Perl... see [`Net::SSH::Perl`](http://search.cpan.org/~schwigon/Net-SSH-Perl-2.01/lib/Net/SSH/Perl.pm), [`Net::Telnet::Cisco`](http://search.cpan.org/~joshua/Net-Telnet-Cisco-1.10/Cisco.pm), [`Net::SNMP`](http://search.cpan.org/~dtown/Net-SNMP-v6.0.1/lib/Net/SNMP.pm), and [`Cisco::Reconfig`](http://search.cpan.org/~muir/Cisco-Reconfig-0.9/Reconfig.pod)
   - Python... see [`pexpect`](https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect), [`netmiko`](https://github.com/ktbyers/netmiko), [`exscript`](https://github.com/knipknap/exscript), [`pysnmp`](https://github.com/etingof/pysnmp), and [`ciscoconfparse`](https://github.com/mpenning/ciscoconfparse)
   - Ruby... see [`net-ssh`](https://rubygems.org/gems/net-ssh/versions/3.1.1), [`snmp`](https://rubygems.org/gems/snmp), and [`cisco`](https://rubygems.org/gems/cisco)
5. Finally, the newer Cisco Nexus products have a Python API (such as [this one](https://opennxos.cisco.com/public/api/python/) for the Nexus 9K); python APIs are  typically easier to  deal with than TCL APIs, but at this point you're restricted to the Nexus family.

---

<sup>Note 1</sup> The only exception I know of is the Cisco 3550, which [doesn't have `tclsh` in 12.2](https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/10386446/tcl-interpreter-cisco-switches).